# VBA InternetExplorer Object Doesn't Retrieve Entire HTML

Tags: vba, excel

I'm using the `InternetExplorer` object in VBA with Excel 2013 to try to parse Gmail emails.

While trying to read the entire HTML of a webpage (in this case an email on Gmail) with `MyBrowser.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML`, the function doesn't return the entire HTML. I mean, some of the objects that I see on the page (for example "sender's name") do not appear in the function's result.

I've also tried using `MyBrowser.document.body.innerHTML`. I get even less information.

Here is the code:

```
Dim MyBrowser As SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
Set MyBrowser = New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer

MyBrowser.Visible = True

'The same problem happens with various gmail URLs
MyBrowser.navigate "https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#section_query/in%3Ainbox/15de2251fc8a10ed"

While MyBrowser.Busy
    DoEvents
Wend

Do While MyBrowser.readyState <> 4
    DoEvents
Loop

Dim entirehtml As String
Dim I As Integer
Dim J As Integer

'entirehtml = MyBrowser.document.body.innerHTML
entirehtml = MyBrowser.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML

LArray = Split(entirehtml, Chr(10))
J = UBound(LArray)

For I = 1 To J
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(I, 1) = LArray(I)
Next I
```

Any ideas?!

M

Comment: Question: Does this project require that you use excel? If not, consider implementing this with JavaScript?

Comment: Since you provide no code, no data, no website to examine, etc., I obviously will not be able to reproduce your problem.  So I can only opine that there is a problem with your code, the website, or possibly a limitation of Excel that you have run into.  I suggest you read SO Help for:  [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Where/how are you viewing the HTML?  If using Debug.Print you should note that the Immediate pane only buffers about 200 lines of text: anything prior to that gets discarded.

Comment: When you say that your function "*doesn't return the entire HTML*" does it only get the first part? Last part? Where does it get cut off? Does it vary, or is it always the same amount that gets returned?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld thanks. I've added the code to the question.

Comment: @TheUnholyProgrammer this is just a small part of a bigger excel project (My Personal CRM that I'm developing)

Comment: @TimWilliams I've added the code. I don't reach the STRING size limitation...

Answer (score 0):

Ok problem solved..

(Thanks @TimWilliams for making me recheck input limitations)

Instead of putting the result of **MyBrowser.document.DocumentElement.innerHTML** into a String, I've added it to the clipboard and apparently I then get all the missing information.